# How to append data to an element

Tags: jquery

I have a scroller that I want to append a single `tr` of data to. I'm not sure how to do this and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction. I am currently using `load` but it is wiping out the rows that were already existing and replacing them with the row that I want to append.

Here is my code so far

```
var refresh = setInterval(function() {
  $("#scroll tbody").load("scroller.asp");
},10000);
```

I found a snippet that I think will work for my case but I'm not sure how to get the loaded data into it. Do I need ajax or is it possible to output the return value of `load` into a variable?

```
  $('<html here>')
      .hide().prependTo('#container').slideDown("slow").css('color','red');
```

Comment: jQuery's `load()` is going to 'Load data from the server and **place the returned HTML into the matched element**.' [link](https://api.jquery.com/load/), sort of similar to `html()`, while you are looking for a single ajax and `append()` thing, so your first code snippet definitely seems off.

Comment: OK, that's right. I'm new to JQ, so bear with me. :)  Should I use AJAX for this?

Comment: It's already answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append content using the jQuery.load() method.use ajax or jquery .get,

```
$.ajax({
  url: "scroller.asp",
  success: function (data) { $("#scroll tbody").append(data); },
  dataType: 'html'
 });
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to prepend the row, would I use prependTo instead of append?

Comment: Hmm... prependTo wipes out all of the existing rows. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Thank you my friend. That worked. At least I was on the right track with the AJAX. I figured I had to use that

Comment: Milind, I'm having another issue. It seems that the new row is being prepended as many times as setInterval calls my server. Is there a way to only have it appended once?

Comment: 1)set some variable as false before prepend.then set some variable as true in setinterval when you append it and check whether variable is false before you append.
2) You can also use jquery to check whether element already exists. if yes then do not append,else append them.

Comment: I think I see what you are referring to but I think I would need to check the string against the new one being appended, no?

Comment: I just looked into that options as well. What I found was: `if($('#scroll tbody').length > 0){
            $("#scroll tbody").prepend(data);
          }`. This doesn't work though. This just checks to see if the variable is present, not if the data is the same. What can I use to test this?

Comment: use double equal to instead of greater tham

Comment: Using double equal stops anything from being prepended.

Answer (score 0):

load function replaces the contents. To have the content appended, you can do an ajax GET request, then append that data into "#scroll tbody".
Something like this:

```
$.get('scroller.asp', function(data){ 
  $("#scroll tbody").append(data);
});
```

Otherwise, create a temporary HTML element, load scroller.asp data into it, and then append that element content into "#scroll tbody"

Answer (score 0):

Actually following function is directly loading `HTML` data in the `table` with id `scroll`

```
$("#scroll tbody").load("scroller.asp");
```

So, everything retrieved from server is getting inserted (replacing old `HTLM`) `table` with id `#scroll` and this is also `ajax` but to manually append the response by modifying it before inserting you may use a different function like:

```
$.get("scroller.asp", function(response){
    $("#scroll tbody").append(response);
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I see that now. I should have seen that on my own but get tunnel vision sometimes. :)

Comment: I seem to make a lot of them though. :)

Comment: @NaN, Me too and I believe I do mistakes probably more than you as I mentioned [in my bio](http://heera.it/who) :-)

Comment: lol. I don't feel so bad then. It also seems to get worse with age.

Comment: Don't worry, every body makes mistakes and then learn and get better by the time.

Comment: Thanks Sheikh. :) As long as I've been using JQ, one would think that I'd have picked it up a lot faster.

Comment: All the best @NaN :-)

Comment: Thanks my friend, same to you!  :)